# Replace text between two characters in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to replace text between two particular characters from a column in mysql table. 
For eg. in my 'email' column, I want to replace 'gmail' from '@gmail.com' and replace it with 'yahoo'.
That is, find text between '@' and '.', and replace the text.
Here is what I tried:

```
UPDATE users
SET email= REPLACE (email, '%@%.%', 'test')
WHERE email LIKE %@%.%;
```

I think such wildcards are used only in WHERE clause. How do I put it in REPLACE() function?
Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace "@gmail." with "@yahoo.", then simply do:

```
UPDATE users
    SET email = REPLACE(email, '@gmail.', '@yahoo.')
WHERE email LIKE '%@gmail.%';
```

If you want the domain to always be gmail, then you can try reconstructing the email:

```
UPDATE users
    SET email = CONCAT(substring_index(email, '@', 1), '@',
                       'yahoo',
                       substring_index(email, '.', -1)
                      )
    WHERE email LIKE '%@%.%';
```

This is not 100% exact -- your problem is undefined when there are multiple "@" or "." in the `email`.  But it might do what you need.